# ASP.Net MVC ScriptBundle: Why specify jQuery version when retrieving from CDN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cdn, bundling-and-minification

I want to use a CDN to reference jQuery for my ASP.Net MVC app.

I do not want to tie the app to a specific version of jQuery.

So, why does every example I can find, seem to reference a specific jQuery version in the CDN path but then use the version agnostic syntax in the '.Include' for the ScriptBundle?

For example:

```
var cdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", cdnPath)
.Include( "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Why does the CDN path not simply point to a directory in which multiple jQuery versions *may* reside and then the CDN server return the latest jQuery version (just as my MVC app would do when fetching scripts from bundles locally).

Or if that is not possible, then why bother with the version agnostic syntax within the .Include() method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _version agnostic syntax_? The MVC code replaces `{version}` with the actual version in your script folder (it just means you can replace your jquery script with a new version without have to explicitely change the code in the bundle

Comment: @Stephen you've just explained exactly what I mean by version agnostic syntax i.e. you don't specify a version number explicitly IOW the bundling setup is agnostic (doesn't know) at compile time which version will be served.

Comment: Yes, but `{version}` is just a placeholder. When you code is run, its replaced with the version that is in your scripts folder. If you currently have (say) `1.9.1`, then that will be loaded in the view. If later you replace it with `2.2.0`, then that will be loaded (the advantage is that you do not need to modify the bundle. Obviously that would not be appropriate for scripts on a CDN because how would it know which one you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some major versions of Jquery are not backward compatible. For example jQuery v2 doesn't run on IE 6/7/8. So if your project has to run on those you will have to stick with version 1

**EDIT**

`Include()` is for local scripts not the ones in CDN. In case that CDN script could not be fetched for what ever reason, local script is used instead.

Comment: OK - so lets say we only support jQuery up to version 1.x.x...so why bother with the version agnostic syntax in the .Include() method?

Comment: `Include()` is for local scripts not the ones in CDN. In case that CDN script could not be fetched for what ever reason, local script is used instead.

Comment: you're above comment is the answer. If you put that in your answer text, I'll accept it.